# Prove this integral inequality

Tags: calculus, normed-spaces, integral-inequality

Prove this assuming $f$ is integratable:
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi\vert f(t)\vert \, dt\leq \sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{\int_{-\pi}^\pi\vert f(t)\vert^2}\, dt =2\pi \Vert f\Vert.$$
I tried to square both sides and use the absolute value integral inequality, however that wasn't the right way.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you heard of the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle.

Comment: I see, so basically the way to prove it is using the fact that $ \left \langle f,1 \right \rangle \leq \left \| f \right \| $ ?

Comment: @lfc the factor $\sqrt{2\pi}$ comes from the fact that $\lVert 1\rVert_2 =\sqrt{2\pi}$ here (you integrate on $[-\pi,\pi]$). For more, read Albert's solution below: the specific case of Holder's inequality used is Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 4):

By using Holder's inequality one writes:
$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(t)|dt
\leq
\Bigg(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}1^{2}dt\Bigg)^{1/2}\Bigg(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(t)|^{2}dt\Bigg)^{1/2}.
$$

Comment: Slick use of Hölder!